# Call a duplicate registration form with other url

Tags: customization, urls

I see there are url's like `register=1` or `action=register`. I have made a php file with my own form in it and I would like to open it with my own link like `registration=2` or something similar to it how can I do this and what this functionality calls ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your functions.php

```
function my_reg_page( $register_url ) {
return home_url() . '/register/';
 }
 add_filter( 'register_url', 'my_reg_page' );
```

This example would return a registration URL http://Yourdomain.com/register/ for the `wp_registration_url()` function

Comment: Thank you so much .. but I have two forms in my theme directory one is call by mysite.com/?register=1 what I want is to call the second form by mysite.com/?register=2

Comment: and please tell me what this functionality calls